# How to enable and disable the view in card item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am using cardview to design this layout. Here when I click **3 dots icon** in any item, a respective card item shows the **transparent Black layer** over this. But what do I need to do that when I click **ITEM-1 Vennila**,it need to show the **transparent Black layout** and then when I click the **ITEM -2 dots**, **ITEM-1 Transparent has to be gone and ITEM-2 Transparent has to be shown.**

[image]

I am using RecyclerView. Please help me to fix it.

This is my Adapter code:

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<Restaurant_Beam> restaurant_prducts;
    Config config;
    Bitmap bmp;
    boolean success = false;
    ArrayList<String> CATEGORYNAME = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> ITEMNAME = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> ITEM_PRICE = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> LIKE_COUNT = new ArrayList<>();
    int clickCount = 0;

    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context context;

    public CardAdapter(List<Restaurant_Beam> superHeroes, Context context) {
        super();

        this.restaurant_prducts = superHeroes;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        Restaurant_Beam restaurant_beam = restaurant_prducts.get(position);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "roboto.medium.ttf");
        Typeface tf1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "roboto.regular.ttf");


        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(config.IMAGE_URL + restaurant_beam.getImageUrl() + ".jpg", ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.productImage, R.drawable.image_1, R.drawable.image_1));  //android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert

        String IMAGE_URL = config.IMAGE_URL + restaurant_beam.getImageUrl() + ".jpg";
        String ITEM_NAME = restaurant_beam.getStr_productName();
        String CATEGORY_NAME = restaurant_beam.getStr_categoryName();
        String PRICE = String.valueOf(restaurant_beam.getStrPrice());
        int LIKECOUNT = (restaurant_beam.getLikeCount());
        String ITEM_ID = restaurant_beam.getProduct_id();
        Log.e("Like Count  ", String.valueOf(LIKECOUNT));

        holder.productImage.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, imageLoader);
        holder.txt_itemName.setText(ITEM_NAME);
        holder.txt_itemName.setTypeface(tf);
        holder.txt_categoryName.setText(CATEGORY_NAME);
        holder.txt_itemName.setTypeface(tf1);
        holder.txt_Price.setText(PRICE);
        holder.txtFav.setText(String.valueOf(LIKECOUNT));
        holder.txtItemID.setText(ITEM_ID);

        holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        ITEMNAME.add(ITEM_NAME);
        CATEGORYNAME.add(CATEGORY_NAME);
        ITEM_PRICE.add(PRICE);
        LIKE_COUNT.add(String.valueOf(LIKECOUNT));


        Log.e("Card Adapter", "Product Name" + String.valueOf(ITEMNAME) + "  Category Name" + CATEGORYNAME + " Price" + ITEM_PRICE + "Restaurant Product" + restaurant_prducts);

        holder.productImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), ProductActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("itemName", holder.txt_itemName.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("categoryName", holder.txt_categoryName.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("Price", Integer.parseInt(holder.txt_Price.getText().toString()));
                i.putExtra("like", Integer.parseInt(holder.txtFav.getText().toString()));
                i.putExtra("itemID", holder.txtItemID.getText().toString());

                view.getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        holder.iv_settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickCount++;

                if (v.isEnabled() == true) {
                    holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.txt_categoryName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.txt_itemName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.iv_settings.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

            }
        });

        holder.viewDetail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked ViewDetail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        holder.addToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked AddToCart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        holder.checkOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked CheckOut", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.e("Restaurant Size", String.valueOf(restaurant_prducts
                .size()));
        return restaurant_prducts.size();
    }

    public void setFilter(String query) {
        Log.e("Adapter Query", query);

        if (ITEMNAME.contains(query)) {
            Log.e("Inside of SetFilter", " Res");
            Log.e("Adapter", String.valueOf(ITEMNAME));
        }

        Log.e("Adapter Query", String.valueOf(ITEMNAME) + " " + CATEGORYNAME + " " + ITEM_PRICE + " ");
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public NetworkImageView productImage;
        public TextView txt_categoryName, txtFav, txtItemID;
        public TextView txt_itemName, txt_Price;
        public CardView cardlist_item;
        public ImageView iv_settings;
        public LinearLayout linearLayout;
        public Button viewDetail, addToCart, checkOut;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            iv_settings = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_settings);
            cardlist_item = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardlist_item);
            txt_itemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_itemName);
            txt_Price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_Price);
            txt_categoryName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_categoryName);
            productImage = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.productImage);
            txtFav = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtFav);
            txtItemID = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemID);
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearTransparent);
            viewDetail = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.butViewDetail);
            addToCart = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.but_addTCart);
            checkOut = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.butCheckOut);
        }
    }
}
```

xml code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardlist_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/curved_shape"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    card_view:cardElevation="7dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/productImage"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/round_shape"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/product_2" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/productImage"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/productImage"
            android:layout_below="@+id/productImage"
            android:background="@drawable/curved_shape"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/listitem_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/Rs"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_Price"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:text="120"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.07"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtFav"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.20"
                android:text=" 153"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtItemID"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.00"
                android:textSize="0dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.07"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_schedule" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTime"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="30 min"
                android:textSize="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@drawable/transparent_layout" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_itemName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/txt_categoryName"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/productImage"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/productImage"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Veg Burger"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_categoryName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/productImage"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/productImage"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="Category Name"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="11dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_settings"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_categoryName"

            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_itemName"
            android:foregroundGravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings3" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearTransparent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/transparent_black"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/butViewDetail"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:text="View Detail" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/but_addTCart"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@color/green"
                android:text="ADD TO CART"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/butCheckOut"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@color/orange"
                android:text="CHECK  OUT"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: you can use popup window for that

Comment: I used this too.But here only I am getting the perfect view.The only need is that  one transparent layer has to shown by respective card item others are not shown at a time while clicking 3 dots.

Comment: ok so store the position of three dot when you click and then call method notifyDataSetChanged(); and check position if (v.isEnabled() == true || position == pos) {
                    holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.txt_categoryName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.txt_itemName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.iv_settings.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a int global variable in your adapter called clickedPos like `int clickedPos = -1;`
In the `bindViewHolder` write -

```
if (clickedPos == position) {
    holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.txt_categoryName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    holder.txt_itemName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    holder.iv_settings.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
} else {
    holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    holder.txt_categoryName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.txt_itemName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.iv_settings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

holder.iv_settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
           clickedPos = position;
           notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

You have to do this as the recyclerview reuses viewholders.

Comment: Thank you so much @Vaibhav Sharma. It is working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

```
try this 
if (pos == position) 
{
    holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.txt_categoryName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    holder.txt_itemName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    holder.iv_settings.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

holder.iv_settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
           pos = position;
           notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Got it...Thank you for ur answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hy I think you should use a clickListener and superpose the black layout in the cardview, by default the black layout has visibility gone and here are the step:

- user clicks on 3 dots
- the recycleview iterate over it's items and set black background visibility to false in all cardviews except the one clicked (you can add a condition check)
- when user clicks on another's cardview the step is repeated and so one.

That's my point of view but may be a better solution exists.
Sorry for my bad english :) good work and good luck